# Google Apps Script Error Exception: Argument too large: subject

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to automate sending Emails from Google sheets but i get this error  Error Exception: Argument too large: subject. I know that there is a limit but is there a way to not get this error?

```
function sendEmaill() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss =app.openById('1Hgbou20hy4XxveATkfsdgU9pvlARI3VfoC-JCdGuwRs'); //subject message
  var sss =app.openById('1GPC3c5u3HTVuEfC7C_lWb8k69ZY3czg6ODtU6oowiGs'); //name email
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  var activeSheet2 = sss.getActiveSheet();
  e = "B" //email
  m = "A2" //name 
  s = "B2"  //subject
  n = "A2"  //message
  amount= 1;                                // email amount
  var Arraye = [];                          //email array
  var Arraya = [];                          // name array
  for(let i = 0 ; i < amount  ; i++) {
        const delta = (i % amount) + 2;
        e = "B";
        Arraye.push(e+delta);
        m = "A";
        Arraya.push(m+delta);
    }
  Logger.log(Arraye)
  Logger.log(Arraya)
  for(let j = 0 ; j < amount  ; j++) {
    emailAdress = activeSheet2.getRange(Arraye[j]).getValue();
    name = activeSheet2.getRange(Arraya[j]).getValue();
    subject = activeSheet.getRange(s).getValue();
    subject = subject.replace("<name>", name);
    message = activeSheet.getRange(n).getValue();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAdress, subject, message);
        
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an obvious thing is to make sure the subject does not exceed the limit (which appears to be 250 for Gmail)

```
subject = subject.substring(0,250);
```